# How many active nodes currently are there mining daily in monero？

Tags: monerod, full-node, mining

Recently, I'm working on some simulations targeting monero mainnet, and want to make them as close as possible to that in the mainnet. To set up the environment for simulations, the number of nodes active in mining is a significant parameter to consider. Really appreciate if anyone who knew something about that can help~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a (incomplete) list: https://monerobase.com/geomap/

It's incomplete because there could be other nodes not known to the monerobase node.

There's no way to tell if they're mining, but they're all validating TXes and blocks.

For mining, we can assume that each pool runs one or more nodes, and there's lots of pools: http://moneropools.com